# LocalDB works fine in Visual Studio IIS, fails when deployed to full IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-express, localdb

I have a code first localdb database in my MVC 4 project and if I run the application in Visual Studio 2012 it connects fine and everything works. When I publish to my full IIS and access the site the database cannot connect and I get :

> "the specified localdb instance does not exist"

I've had other problems, it seems localdb is a nightmare to deploy! I followed all the advice here also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx

I'm still having no luck, why does it work perfectly in VS IIS Express and not 'real' IIS?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if i get it but most of the time this error occurs due to connection issue. how is your connection string?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing and developing against a full instance of SQL server to avoid this problem when deploying to **IIS** locally.

**LocalDB** is a very small subset (around **30 MB**) of SQL server so you can develop against it with out installing the entire server application.  This works very nicely along with **IIS Express** during development.  For deployment, your database for that environment should be hosted an a full fledged SQL Server Express/Developer/Standard/etc and your connection string should be changed to reflect

As you pointed out [the post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx) might shed some light on a workaround but only for development using a Local IIS Server (not IIS Express) with **LocalDB**.