# Cannot connect to named shared LocalDB instance

Tags: iis, localdb

I spent hours on this with no success. Any help appriciated:

I create LocalDB instance

```
sqllocaldb create test
```

i start that instance

```
sqllocaldb start test
```

i share that instance with same user account that owns the original instance

```
sqllocaldb share "domain\user" test testShared
```

Both instances are in "running" state.

I launch MS SQL Management studio and try to connect to instances. Results:

I'm able to connect to both instances using named pipes - OK.

I'm able to connect to (localdb)\test - OK.

I'm not able to connect to (localdb)\.\testShared - NOT OK.

Error message:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)`

Any ideas? I tried that on 4 different computers. It works correctly on two of them. 3 of coputers are connected to domain (so it has probably nothing to do with domain environment).

In SQL Configuration Manager - all protocols are enabled.

What I need to achieve - share the LocalDB instance with IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 account according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx#SharedLocalDB).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the exact steps, as you described them, all you need to do is to restart your instance. It is required after you share it, so that it listens on the public pipe with the well known name that was assigned to it by the sharing process.

Comment: OK, that was it. I'm ashamed :) THANK YOU! I'm now able to connect the instance using sql mgmt studio. I moved to the next step which is sharing the instance with IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 account. I'm not able to connect the instance from my web application (the app. runs under ASP.NET v4.0 pool which runs under ApplicationPoolIdentity. When I try to connect using name I get different error then when I try the pipe.

Comment: USING NAME: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. )

Comment: USING PIPE:  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Pool settings: 
            <add name="ASP.NET v4.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
  <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
     </add>

Comment: Probably you're missing a login for the ASP.NET pool user on your LocalDB instance. See if this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx

Comment: Then I ran out of simple solutions :-) You should probably create another question with detailed description of your configuration and symptoms, etc. (one thing to try is to look at the shared instance name in the connection string, maybe a common missing double-escape problem?)

Comment: I've double checked these things. Thank you for all contributions, I'll consider another question. And also thank you for great blog posts on msdn. :)

Comment: Any word on this? I'm having the same problem with IIS 8... And I'm not the only one it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728078/localdb-works-fine-in-visual-studio-iis-fails-when-deployed-to-full-iis

Comment: This needs to be added as documentation to the `SqlLocalDB` exe! It's not clear at all that this is required before shares work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting "The specified LocalDB instance does not exist."  Dunno why.

Answer (score 3):

> you need to enable setProfileEnvironment. This requires editing
>   applicationHost.config file which is usually located in
>   C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. Following the instructions from KB
>   2547655 we should enable both flags for Application Pool ASP.NET v4.0,
>   like this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx

```
    <applicationPools>
<add name="DefaultAppPool">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
 </add>
        <add name="ASP.NET v4.0" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
        </add>
```